# PHP form post being called twice

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have a form that posts to the same page it is declared on. The problem is that it appears to be called twice when submitted. Here is the code:

```
function user_data_form() {

    add_ajax_validation();

    // Form verication start
    if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
        switch($_POST["action"]) {
            case "validate_form":
                ajax_validate();
                break;
            case "update_user_data":
                $wp_user_object = wp_get_current_user();
                $id = $wp_user_object->ID;
                if ( 0 == $wp_user_object->ID ) {
                    redirect(get_permalink(get_page_by_title( 'Sign in' )), array(
                        "message" => 8
                    ));
                } else {
                    $form_data = array(
                        "verified" => false,
                        "email" => $_POST["email"],
                        "first_name" => $_POST["first_name"],
                        "last_name" => $_POST["last_name"],
                        "password" => $_POST["password"],
                        "old_password" => $_POST["old_password"],
                        "verify_password" => $_POST["verify_password"]
                    );
                    $form_data["verification"] = array(
                        "old_password" => wp_check_password($form_data["old_password"], $wp_user_object->user_pass, $id),
                        "email" => validate("email", $form_data["email"]),
                        "password" => validate("old_password", $form_data["old_password"]),
                        "verify_password" => validate("verify_password", $form_data["old_password"], $form_data["verify_password"])
                    );
                    if ($form_data["verification"]["old_password"]) {
                        if ($form_data["email"] != $wp_user_object->user_email && $form_data["verification"]["email"]) {
                            invalidate_email($id, $form_data["email"]);
                            $message = message('success', 'Account information updated, an email has been dispatched to <strong>'.$form_data["email"].'</strong> with details on how to confirm your new email address');
                            $form_data["email"] = $wp_user_object->user_email;
                        }
                        if ($form_data["first_name"] != $wp_user_object->get("first_name")) {
                            update_user_meta($id, 'first_name', $form_data["first_name"]);
                        }
                        if ($form_data["last_name"] != $wp_user_object->get("last_name")) {
                            update_user_meta($id, 'last_name', $form_data["last_name"]);
                        }
                        if ($form_data["verification"]["password"]["result"] && $form_data["verification"]["verify_password"]["result"]) {
                            wp_set_password($form_data["password"], $id);
                        }
                        if (!message) {
                            $message = message('success', 'Account information updated');
                        }
                    } else {
                        $message = message('error', '<b>Error:</b> Incorrect password');
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    // Form verication end

    // Create form
    if (!$form_data["verified"]) {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $new_email = get_metadata("user", $current_user->user_ID, "new_email", true);
        $email_expires = get_metadata("user", $current_user->user_ID, "email_expires", true);
        $form = 'You can view and update your account settings using the following form:
                <form action="#" method="post" class="user-data">
                '.$message.'
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_user_data" />
                <div class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="text" data-validation-method="email" class="text" data-validation-ignore="'.encode($current_user->user_email).'" value="'.(($form_data["email"]) ? $form_data["email"] : $current_user->user_email).'" placeholder="youremail@somesite.com" data-validation-response="'.(($form_data["email"] == $current_user->user_email) ? NULL : encode($form_data["verification"]["email"])).'" />
                        '.(($new_email) ? '<span class="fail">An email has been sent to the above address to change email to <strong>'.$new_email.'</strong></span>' : NULL).'
                        <span class="info">You will recieve a validation email to your new email address. If you don\'t confirm within 24 hours your email address will revert to the last validated one.</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="first_name">First name: <sup>1</sup></label>
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="text" value="'.$current_user->user_firstname.'"/>
                        <label for="last_name">Last name: <sup>1</sup></label>
                        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="text" value="'.$current_user->user_lastname.'"/>
                        <span class="info"><sup>1</sup> Required to issue certificates.</span>
                        <div class="fieldgroup">
                            <span class="info">
                                <strong>Note:</strong> Only fill in these fields if you wish to change your password.
                            </span>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="password">New password:</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" data-validation-method="password" class="text" value="'.$form_data["password"].'" data-validation-response="'.((strlen($form_data["password"]) > 0) ? encode($form_data["verification"]["password"]) : NULL ).'" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="verify_password">Retype your new password:</label>
                                <input type="password" name="verify_password" id="verify_password" class="text" data-validation-method="verify_password" data-validation-requires="password" value="'.$form_data["verify_password"].'" data-validation-response="'.((strlen($form_data["verify_password"]) > 0) ? encode($form_data["verification"]["verify_password"]) : NULL ).'" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="password">Current password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="old_password" id="old_password" class="text" value=""/>
                            <span class="info">Your current password is required to make changes to your account information. Have you <a href="'.get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'Reset your password' ) ).'">forgotten your password?</a></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" id="submitbtn" class="button omega" name="submit" value="Update my account information" />
                </div>
            </form>';
    } else {
        redirect(get_permalink(get_page_by_title( 'My account' )), array(
            "message" => 2
        ));
    }
    return $form;
}
```

The problem is that `invalidate_email()` gets called twice. Although it should only fire when `$_POST["action"] == "update_user_data"` which should only be after the form is submitted. I can't work out where the second call is coming from.

Here is my `invalidate_email()` function:

```
function invalidate_email($user_id, $new_email) {
    $key = createKey($new_email);
    $activation_url = get_permalink(get_page_by_title( 'Activate' ))."?key=".$key."&id=".$user_id."&type=email";
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'new_email', $new_email);
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'email_activation_key', $key);
    $expires = get_metadata("user", $user_id, "email_expires", true);
    if (!$expires) {
        $expires = time() + 86400000; //86400000 milliseconds = 24 Hours
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'email_expires', $expires);
    }

    $message = "A request to update your email for your account on First steps has been made, please confirm your email address by clicking the following link: <p />";
    $message .= "<a href='".$activation_url."'>".$activation_url."</a> <p />";
    $message .= "If you did not request the change your account may be comprimised and we recommend you change your password from the 'my account' page. <p />";
    $message .= "If you do not confirm your new email address within 24 hours the request will expire and you will have to request a new one.";

    email($new_email, "First steps - Confirm your new email address", "Confirm email address change", $message);
}
```

and `email()`:

```
function email($to, $subject, $heading, $message, $attachments = NULL) {
    $headers = array('From: First steps <info@rcnhca.org.uk>', 'Content-type: text/html');
    $body = '<table width="100%" style="background:#ECECEC;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
                <tr width="100%" style="background: #3393b5;">
                    <td align="center">
                        <table width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="height:45px; vertical-align:middle;">
                                    <a href="'.get_bloginfo("url").'"><img alt="First steps for health care assistants" src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/library/images/logo.png" width="347" height="32" style="vertical-align:middle;display:block;" /></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="padding: 10px 0px;">
                        <table width="500" style="padding: 10px;background:#FFFFFF;border:1px solid #BCBCBC;margin:0px 10px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;line-height:1.5em;text-align:left;"><font face="verdana">
                                    <h2 style="margin-top: 0.1em; font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 0.5em; color: #333333; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; margin-bottom: 0.7em;">'.$heading.'</h2>
                                    '.$message.'
                                </font></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table width="500">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-size:12px;line-height:1.5em;text-align:left;"><font face="verdana">We are committed to keeping your email private, we do not share your address with third-parties.</font></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table> ';
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments);
}
```

I am positive it is not an Ajax call (so ignore `add_ajax_validation()`) because it happens even if I remove Ajax verification (which is what this function does). I have also checked for the existence of the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` which should be present as all my Ajax is performed by jQuery that header should be present.

**EDIT:** In response to @Oli

I performed a `debug_backtrace()` to see what was calling the function, here is my backtrace:

```
$trace= debug_backtrace();
$funcs = array();
foreach ($trace as $func) {
    array_push($funcs, $func['function']);
}
$funcs = implode('\n', $funcs);
```

Output 1:

```
invalidate_email
user_data_form
call_user_func
do_shortcode_tag
preg_replace_callback
do_shortcode
pre_process_shortcode
call_user_func_array
apply_filters
wp_trim_excerpt
call_user_func_array
apply_filters
get_the_excerpt
require_once 
load_template
locate_template
get_header
include
require_once
require
```

Output 2:

```
invalidate_email
user_data_form
call_user_func
do_shortcode_tag
preg_replace_callback
do_shortcode
pre_process_shortcode
call_user_func_array
apply_filters
the_content
include
require_once
require
```

At `call_user_func()` and beyond this is all done by the WordPress CMS as a result of the following function call: `add_shortcode('user_data_form', 'user_data_form', 134);`

Comment: Show us the function invalidate_email()

Comment: thanks, now I'm going to ask to show the email() function - I'm guessing that's where the mail() function is being called.

Comment: @Duniyadnd Updated question... it calls `wp_mail()` which is a built in function of the WordPress CMS

Comment: Not related to your problem, but I'd advise against using 'global $current_user;'

Comment: @Oli that is a global variable created by the WordPress CMS... see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo

Comment: Ok..this might be far-fetched, but would it be possible to throw a new exception to check the stacktrace of where in the code the function is called? Use a session to track the second time the function is called..

Comment: Thanks, too bad I'm no wordpress expert..but it's clear the first time templates are loaded, you're sure the second call wasn't through some ajax function? The user_data_form is called twice, so I'd investigate that further..maybe someone else can do more with the stacktraces ;)

Comment: I googled a bit for 'user function called twice wordpress'.. try this: define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);

Comment: @Oli Unfortunately that doesn't work, thats for saving pages in the CMS when it keeps multiple revisions, and only gets called if you save a page from the backend. Also not Ajax as I check for `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` and all my Ajax calls are done using jQuery which adds that header.

Comment: Hmm well I'm outta ideas..perhaps extend your stacktrace with linenumbers and detailed info about the files and includes used. And then go on a debugging-rampage..And of course check google for 'double function wordpress' etc.

Comment: Can you try removing the `invalidate_email()` function and see how it goes ?

Comment: @Oli Thanks for your time mate, I solved it see my answer. Apologies as the information I supplied wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Put `var_dump(func_get_args())` to investigate and detect what parameters are you receives into `invalidate_email` function.</strike>

Comment: It only receives the parameters it is meant to - `$user_id` and `$new_email`. I'm not sure how this helps see why it is being called twice.

Comment: Be sure that function not receiving duplicate function so in this function not receiving duplicates before...

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand

Comment: I think you received twice because you receive from function as twice. You receive 2 parameters but not received so, before this function it's pass. After this function something not working.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I've noticed this before with mail(). When you have a "To" in the headers section and a variable for "to" in the first parameter for mail() - it gets sent twice. You may want to remove the piece for the header and try that.</strike>

Should have read the question closer.

Comment: Thanks but it is not just the mail being sent twice, but the function is called twice as each time it generates a new and different `$activation_url`.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like such a nincompoop but I just realised this was self inflicted. I had this piece of code that attempts to avoid WordPress' auto formatting function `wpautop`. It appears to fire them twice.

```
function pre_process_shortcode($content) {
    global $shortcode_tags;
    // Backup current registered shortcodes and clear them all out
    $orig_shortcode_tags = $shortcode_tags;
    $shortcode_tags = array();
        add_shortcode('registration_form', 'registration_form', 134);
        add_shortcode('login_form', 'login_form', 134);
        add_shortcode('user_data_form', 'user_data_form', 134);
        add_shortcode('activation_code', 'activation_code', 134);
        add_shortcode('logout_code', 'logout_code', 134);
        add_shortcode('reset_password_form', 'reset_password_form', 134);
    // Do the shortcode (only the one above is registered)
    $content = do_shortcode($content);
    // Put the original shortcodes back
    $shortcode_tags = $orig_shortcode_tags;
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'pre_process_shortcode', 13);
```

I changed this to just:

```
    add_shortcode('registration_form', 'registration_form', 134);
    add_shortcode('login_form', 'login_form', 134);
    add_shortcode('user_data_form', 'user_data_form', 134);
    add_shortcode('activation_code', 'activation_code', 134);
    add_shortcode('logout_code', 'logout_code', 134);
    add_shortcode('reset_password_form', 'reset_password_form', 134);
```

Which of course creates other problems but at least it solves this issue, and I will find another way to do what I wanted before. Sorry to anyone who spent time trying to resolve this issue as you would never have worked this out from the information I supplied.